# Decorate VSCode (jupyter) interactive window with (python) process-id

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter

I often debug a python interactive session that calls external C#, C++ or CUDA code by attaching an external debugger to the python process. I always type `os.getpid()`, but in trying to save a few keystrokes, I wonder if there is a way to decorate the interactive window in VS Code with the `pid`? E.g. ref. the attached screenshot, add it somewhere/somehow[image] to the other meta-info?

Comment: Hi there. I'm a developer on the vscode Jupyter tools. We don't currently have this. But if you would like filing an issue in our github repo would be the way to go about getting this added. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues

Comment: Thanks @IanHuff . see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/6638